# Inconsistent results parsing unicode strings in perl unpack

Tags: bash, perl, unicode

I am preparing a script to do a pairwise comparison of characters written in a foreign script, and I would like to extract individual characters from target words for comparison.

When characters with address > 256 are hard-coded into the script, `unpack` correctly determines the address: e.g., the sequence of U+0268 (=616 decimal) (`LATIN SMALL LETTER I WITH STROKE`) followed by the modifier U+0301 (=769 decimal) (`COMBINING ACUTE ACCENT`) is correctly parsed (first MWE).

From the command line or an external text file, however, the parsing is done bytewise. So instead of 616 I get (201,168), and instead of 769 I get (204,129). In the two byte case it's generally X→(d1,d2) where X=64×(d1−194)+d2. (second MWE).

```
$ perl -e 'use utf8; @a= unpack("U*","fɨ́kà"); print "@a\n";'
102 616 769 107 97 768
```

(fɨ́kà)

```
$ echo 'use utf8; @a=unpack("U*",$ARGV[0]); print "@a\n";' | perl - fɨ́kà
102 201 168 204 129 107 97 204 128
```

(fÉ¨ÌkaÌ€)

Is there something I can do to get the second MWE to work correctly? Post-processing so that (201,168) → (616) seems too crude. The script is being run from the bash shell.

```
$ echo $BASH_VERSION
4.3.30(1)-release

This is perl 5, version 20, subversion 2 (v5.20.2) built for x86_64-linux-gnu-thread-multi
(with 39 registered patches, see perl -V for more detail)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is that Perl doesn't decode commandline arguments as UTF-8 by default. Passing the switch -CA makes it do that:

```
$ echo 'use utf8; @a=unpack("U*",$ARGV[0]); print "@a\n";' | perl -CA - fɨ́kà
102 616 769 107 97 768
```

You'll probably want -CAS (args + STD* file handles) or even -CASD (that plus every file you open)